# How to write above specific bars in bar graphs using pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I would like to put values above a few bars in my bar graph.
[image: This is what I would like]

For those bars whose value exceeds 1.7, I clip off the bar at 1.7 and write its actual value on top of that bar. Here is what I have (for just 4 of these bars):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        %title={Comparing Push, Pull, Hyb, Gunrock(norm wrt Push) for Real-World Graphs for CC},
        width=\columnwidth,
        compat=newest,
        xlabel={Inputs},
        ylabel={Execution time (normalized)},
        ybar,
        bar width=7pt,
        symbolic x coords={RMAT-1M-1M, RMAT-15, RMAT-16, RMAT-17},
        xtick=data,
        enlargelimits=0.15,
        legend style={at={(0.5, -0.2)}, anchor=north, legend columns=-1},
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(RMAT-1M-1M, 1) (RMAT-15, 1) (RMAT-16, 1) (RMAT-17, 1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(RMAT-1M-1M, 0.9853) (RMAT-15, 1.0452) (RMAT-16, 0.8697) (RMAT-17, 0.457)};
    \addplot coordinates {(RMAT-1M-1M, 0.9375) (RMAT-15, 0.9408) (RMAT-16, 0.718) (RMAT-17, 0.4078)};
    \addplot coordinates {(RMAT-1M-1M, 1.7) (RMAT-15, 1.7) (RMAT-16, 1.7) (RMAT-17, 1.7)};
    \legend{Push(Subway), Pull, Hybrid, Gunrock}
    \node[above] at ($(axis cs:RMAT-1M-1M,1.7)$) {3.4};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But this puts the 3.4 not exactly above the 4th bar under RMAT-1M-1M as I would like it to be. If I change the axis cs line to: axis cs:RMAT-1M-1M+0.5,1.7 this gives an error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please always post complete compilable code starting with `\documentclass...` and ending with `\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=10cm,
ybar,
bar width=7pt,
symbolic x coords={RMAT-1M-1M, RMAT-15, RMAT-16, RMAT-17},
xtick=data,
enlargelimits=0.15,
]
\addplot coordinates {(RMAT-1M-1M, 1) (RMAT-15, 1) (RMAT-16, 1) (RMAT-17, 1)};
\addplot coordinates {(RMAT-1M-1M, 0.9853) (RMAT-15, 1.0452) (RMAT-16, 0.8697) (RMAT-17, 0.457)};
\addplot coordinates {(RMAT-1M-1M, 0.9375) (RMAT-15, 0.9408) (RMAT-16, 0.718) (RMAT-17, 0.4078)};
\addplot coordinates {(RMAT-1M-1M, 1.7) (RMAT-15, 1.7) (RMAT-16, 1.7) (RMAT-17, 1.7)};
\node[above] at ([xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/bar shift}]axis cs:RMAT-1M-1M,1.7) {3.4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bar graph with label above one bar]

This is how much each bar is automatically shifted:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/bar shift auto/.style={
        /pgf/bar shift={%
            % total width = n*w + (n-1)*skip
            % -> subtract half for centering
            -0.5*(\numplotsofactualtype*\pgfplotbarwidth + (\numplotsofactualtype-1)*(#1)) +
            % the '0.5*w' is for centering
            (.5+\plotnumofactualtype)*\pgfplotbarwidth + \plotnumofactualtype*(#1)},
}, }
```

-in case you want the exact number to shift your label for each of the four bars in the example.